# Weird compiling problem - DLL not compiled the same on some machines

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2005

I'm not asking for the SO to tell me what the problem is, I'm just asking what **sanity checks** should I run in a case like this.

Using Visual Studio 2005, plain c++ project. Actual code is:

```
int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

No pre-compiled headers. Exported with a DEF file:

```
LIBRARY testdll
EXPORTS
    Sum
```

Compiled on a test machine (VS2005 again), the DLL works on other machines (64 bit and 32 bit tested, always compiled with a Win32 target platform). Compiled on my machine (64 bit, same project, same properties), the DLL works **only** on my machine, on others it starts the Just-In-Time Debugger (or crashes horribly if JIT isn't installed):

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in Caller.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

At first I was calling it with [j](/questions/tagged/j) on my test machines, and that would fail too, giving me (with `cder`) a "file not found" error.

Other symptom: File size is different, my machine gives the DLL an extra 512 bytes.

My system configuration:

- Windows Vista - 64 bit
- VS2005 Version 8.050727.867 (vsvista.050727-8600)
- .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727 SP2

Tested environments:

- Windows XP - 32 bit (virtual machine)
- VS2005 Version 8.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
- .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727 SP2
- Windows XP - 64 bit
- VS2005 Version 8.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
- .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727 SP2

Comment: Can it have something to do with your VS version having a different version of the VC runtime DLLs?

Comment: I'd begin by double-checking that the command line VS creates for the compile and link are identical.  And then run them manually on each platform to see if there are any differences in what is displayed.

Comment: @wallyk: I copied the project from my original computer to the other. Nonetheless, I checked both command lines, they are identical.

Comment: @BoazYaniz: That's my latest theory, but it would only work if the VC runtime DLL is different between Vista64 and XP64. Or maybe there's another delta I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that "Win32 target platform" is wrong configured on your 64-bit machine. I recommend you to start "Visual Studio 2005 Command Prompt" and use

> dumpbin.exe /headers YouDll.dll

to examine the "wrong" DLL which will be produced on the 64-bit machine. You can compare it with the "good" DLL. I suppose that you will immediately see the differences. WinDiff.exe can help you additionally.

One small general advice: consider to use `EXTERN_C` and `WINAPI` (or [__stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx)) for all functions which you export from the DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the general advice. It was a project I threw together quickly to demonstrate, but you are right in your recommendations.

Comment: Well, there's definitely a difference using dumpbin. code size and addresses differ mostly.

Comment: @MPelletier: could you post the exact results of WinDiff compare of the both outputs?

Comment: I was able to recompile the DLL with /MT instead of /MD (no /clr, of course) on my "bad" machine and the DLL worked on all machines. I'm currently exploring that venue. How the heck do you save results in WinDiff?

Comment: @MPelletier: You can see that in Import table: "dumpbin /imports yourdll.dll". The Dll which is compiled with respect of /MD has dependences from C/C++ runtime DLL which can be not on all computers installed. The DLL compiled with /MT is longer, but it include the code of all C/C++ functions which it uses.

Comment: @MPelletier: [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is very good tool to see DLL dependencies.

Comment: @Oleg: So for a project of even this simplicity, I should either compile with /MT or deploy with basic required VC runtime DLLs?

Comment: @MPelletier: Yes, it's correct. If you don't use /MT you have to include in the setup of your program the Windows Installer merge module of the corresponding VC Runtime (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290(v=vs.80).aspx) for details). You can deploy the VC runtime to the destination computers in any other ways. Mostly is you have only one executable the usage of /MT is better. If you have program with many DLLs used VC runtime it would be better to use /MD and deploy VC Runtime. It will reduce the code multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Open both DLLs in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what's different.  Preferably do this on a machine where one DLL doesn't run right.

Comment: That gave me some sort of a clue, basically the "bad pc" has an extra missing DLL, MSVCM80.DLL.